# BackgroundSubtractor throws 'Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat' Exception

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, background-subtraction

*I have searched a lot for this problem, but I did not find any solution.*

I have a program which receives JPEG format file data through socket (in bytes), then I convert the byte array to `OpenCV Mat` object as below:

```
Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(byteArray), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

It converts well without any exception, then (for test case to ensure the data is OK) I convert the `Mat` object to `BufferedImage` and then show it in a `JPanel`, everything goes well without any exception.

**But** when I apply:

```
mog2.apply(mat, foregroundImg, -1); // tried 1, 0, 0.003 etc
```

**OR**

```
knn.apply(mat, foregroundImg, -1); // tried 1, 0, 0.003 etc
```

the `mat` to `BackgroundSubtractor` (any of `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` or `BackgroundSubtractorKNN`) then it throws the exception with the following message:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2494
```

**Then** I change the type of `Mat` as follow, but throws the same error

```
Mat newMat = new Mat();
mat.convertTo(newMat, CvType.CV_8UC3)
```

---

**For** test I have done some other operation on this `mat` to ensure that it works with other OpenCV functions, **but it all works well** like:

Convert to gray

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

Do threshold

```
Imgproc.threshold(grayImg, grayImg, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```

**And so on...** all works without any exception.

**Special case:** If I use a webcam (integrated or USB camera) or read frames from a video file, everything goes well without any exception.

**Now** I don't know why this error or exception happens, is this a bug with the `BackgroundSubtractor` or there is anything wrong in data?

**Special Note:** I am using OpenCV latest version (3.0) in `Java` Languange

Comment: Hello Bahramdun,  I am new to Opencv. Can you help me how to initialize background subtractor mog2 in java. I am not able to do that.

Comment: Hi! It is easy you can just do the following that is OK: `mog2 = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();` Or `knn = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN();` and also it is better to do this as will `mog2.setShadowValue(0);'

Comment: Thanks a lot... I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are so welcome! Wish you Good Luck!!