# Issue with OpenCV BackgroundSubtractor

Tags: java, opencv, background-subtraction

I am trying to use `BackgroundSubtractor` class of OpenCV in Java, which two sub-classes `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` and `BackgroundSubtractorKNN` and going subtract the background from a video stream frame, these frame are coming from Network IP camera in `bytes` in `JPEG` format, after that I covert the bytes to OpenCV `Mat` object in this way:

```
Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(data), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

and then pass it to `BackgroundSubtractor` apply method:

```
mog2.apply(mat, foregroundImg, -1); // tried 1, 0, 0.003 etc
// or
//knn.apply(mat, foregroundImg, -1); // tried 1, 0, 0.003 etc
```

It will throws Exception with the following message:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2494
```

Now I don't know what can be the reason. Is it a bug with the `BackgroundSubtractor` or there is any wrong in code.

---

For ensuring that the converted Mat has no problem, I used some other OpenCV functions to test if says the same Error, but works will all of the other functions like:

Convert to gray

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

Do threshold

```
Imgproc.threshold(grayImg, grayImg, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
```

**Note:** When I use webcam (integrated or USB) or reading frames from a video file, everything going well with same code.

**Edited:** The whole error message:

```
 OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2494
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2494: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
]
    at com.test.subtractor.VideoStream.start(VideoStream.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2494: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
]
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the background subtraction part, but rather in the decoding part. Your JPEG images are corrupted (or, at least, OpenCV JPEG decoder can't decode them).

Comment: I also have the same idea as yours, in exception it says there found two extra bytes, now how to detect and delete them, or how to correctly decode the bytes to Mat object? Thanks

Comment: You're decoding correctly. The problem is in the stream. You should check why it's corrupted. Are you sure you wait to receive the whole image?

Comment: I am getting the bytes via a Java wrapper to the IP cam .dll files, after when I connected to the camera then I use the function something like `getJPEG(byte[] bytes);`. then it should be OK, I tried very very much, but really did not find any good solution for this problem.

Comment: And also how it works with the other functions although it is a corrupted image?

Comment: That's actually wierd, but since I cannot reproduce this, I can't tell..

Comment: Thank you sir! I have solved one problem which says the corrupted image, I think that was an OpenCV warning. But now the second Exception still exist, which says: `OpenCV Error: Bad flag....Unrecognized or unsupported array type`, I think it is the real error.

Comment: Ok, that's much easier to correct. Please post the whole error

Comment: Thanks in advance if this problem corrected!! I edited the question, it was too long to put here.

Comment: That's not as I expected... The problem still seems not to be in the background subtraction part, but the way you create the matrices.

Comment: You can check this question about the same problem, maybe more clear than this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368799/backgroundsubtractor-throws-unrecognized-or-unsupported-array-type-in-function